# Data transaction using WIFI in iPhone to other phones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, wifi

I am an `iOS` developer, I need to transfer datas from **iPhone** to other phones via `wifi` and vice versa in my new application . Is it possible in iOS ? . Is there any sample code in `Objective C` for this?

Answer (score 0):

[I have made a Cydia tweak which does just this.](https://github.com/H2CO3/FileTransfer)

Comment: Can u please give me a buildable Xcode project. i can't understand anything from this.

Comment: @vishnu I don't use Xcode. It's fairly simple to build - just set the sysroot in the Makefile and `make`. If you claim to be a developer (which you explicitly do in your quesion), you should be able to use simple command line build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use bonjour to search for devices. Then use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to send and receive data.